# missing dependecies resteasy and wildfly

Tags: java, wildfly, resteasy

I am trying to build a rest service on my application , here is the [proyect in github](https://github.com/robertofd1995/SDI3/tree/REST)

My process to make a rest service for the userService was the following.

First I create [the interface](https://github.com/robertofd1995/SDI3/blob/REST/sdi3-22Web/src/com/sdi/rest/UserServiceRest.java) with the operations that will be possible to do with my rest service

Then I add to the model of user the annotations that are needed
[User Model Class](https://github.com/robertofd1995/SDI3/blob/REST/sdi3-22Ejb/ejbModule/com/sdi/model/User.java)

After that I implement the userService [UserServiceImpl](https://github.com/robertofd1995/SDI3/blob/REST/sdi3-22Web/src/com/sdi/rest/impl/UserServiceRestImpl.java)

I add to the [web.xml](https://github.com/robertofd1995/SDI3/blob/REST/sdi3-22Web/WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml) the configuration elements that are needed

And then to end I create the [class Application](https://github.com/robertofd1995/SDI3/blob/REST/sdi3-22Web/src/com/sdi/rest/impl/Application.java) to make RestEasy which class should use.

Then when I try to run this on the server when I start it I have the following stacktrace:

```
13:22:51,124 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."sdi3-22.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sdi3-22.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000075: Normal scoped managed bean implementation class has a public field:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] public org.jboss.resteasy.core.AcceptHeaderByFileSuffixFilter.mediaTypeMappings
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.checkBeanImplementation(ManagedBean.java:218)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractClassBean.internalInitialize(AbstractClassBean.java:74)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.internalInitialize(ManagedBean.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.RIBean.initialize(RIBean.java:65)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$5.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:114)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentBeanDeployer$5.doWork(ConcurrentBeanDeployer.java:112)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
    at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [rt.jar:1.7.0_71]
    ... 3 more

13:22:51,141 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "sdi3-22.ear")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"sdi3-22.ear\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"sdi3-22.ear\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DefinitionException: WELD-000075: Normal scoped managed bean implementation class has a public field:  [EnhancedAnnotatedFieldImpl] public org.jboss.resteasy.core.AcceptHeaderByFileSuffixFilter.mediaTypeMappings"}}
13:22:51,219 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "sdi3-22.ear" (runtime-name : "sdi3-22.ear")
13:22:51,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "notaneitor-ds.xml" (runtime-name : "notaneitor-ds.xml")
13:22:51,220 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS018559: Deployed "hsqldb.jar" (runtime-name : "hsqldb.jar")
13:22:51,222 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."sdi3-22.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."sdi3-22.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
```

And then this :

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.EjbAdminService".SERVICE_ENDPOINT (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.LocalAdminService".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.RemoteAdminService".REMOTE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbAdminService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.EjbApplicationService".SERVICE_ENDPOINT (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.LocalApplicationService".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.RemoteApplicationService".REMOTE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.EjbLoginService".SERVICE_ENDPOINT (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.LocalLoginService".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.RemoteLoginService".REMOTE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.EjbRatingService".SERVICE_ENDPOINT (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.LocalRatingService".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.RemoteRatingService".REMOTE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.EjbSeatService".SERVICE_ENDPOINT (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.LocalSeatService".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.RemoteSeatService".REMOTE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbSeatService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.VIEW."com.sdi.business.ServicesFactory".LOCAL (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbServicesFactory.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.EjbTripService".SERVICE_ENDPOINT (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.RemoteTripService".REMOTE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbTripService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbUserService.START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbUserService.VIEW."com.sdi.business.impl.RemoteUserService".REMOTE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbUserService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbUserService.WeldInterceptorBindingsService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbUserService.WeldInstantiator] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbUserService.ejb.non-functional-timerservice (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbUserService.START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".deploymentCompleteService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."sdi3-22.ear".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".ee.ComponentRegistry (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Ejb".UndertowDeploymentInfoService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".jndiDependencyService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbUserService.START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.START, JBAS014799: ... and 5 more ] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformation (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbLoginService.START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".moduleDeploymentRuntimeInformationStart, service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbRatingService.START, service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Ejb.jar".component.EjbApplicationService.START, JBAS014799: ... and 4 more ] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.infrastructure.LoggingInitialization".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.infrastructure.LoggingInitialization".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.infrastructure.LoggingInitialization".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Web".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Web", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.infrastructure.LoggingInitialization".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.infrastructure.LoggingInitialization".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.presentation.filter.LoginFilter".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.presentation.filter.LoginFilter".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.presentation.filter.LoginFilter".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Web".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Web", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.presentation.filter.LoginFilter".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sdi.presentation.filter.LoginFilter".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Web".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Web", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".CREATE (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Web".UndertowDeploymentInfoService, service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host."/sdi3-22.Web", service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".WeldInstantiator (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-22.Web.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet".START] 
  service jboss.deployment.subunit."sdi3-22.ear"."sdi3-
```

And it continues.

I don't know where is the problem.
Thanks for the help

UPDATE: The problem was the amount of libraries that I have in the project that wasn't needed as @Harald said because that libraries were already in wildfly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have some RESTEasy implementation classes included in your WAR or EAR.

You should only depend on the JAX-RS API, the implementation is provided by WildFly.